# OData, ASP.NET Core 3.1 WebApi, System.Text.Json not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, odata, system.text.json

We are trying to remove NewtonSoft from our ASP.NET Core 3.1 project which provides OData endpoints. However, it seems ODATA is not yet supported by System.Text.Json. Can you please suggest some workaround, we even tried using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData 7.4.0-beta.

http://localhost:56542/v1/masterlists/PHASE?$select=name

```
[
{
    "Instance": null,
    "Container": {},
    "ModelID": "26fdaf5e-602e-4d6d-8480-80c576110494",
    "UntypedInstance": null,
    "InstanceType": null,
    "UseInstanceForProperties": false
},
{
    "Instance": null,
    "Container": {},
    "ModelID": "26fdaf5e-602e-4d6d-8480-80c576110494",
    "UntypedInstance": null,
    "InstanceType": null,
    "UseInstanceForProperties": false
},
{
    "Instance": null,
    "Container": {},
    "ModelID": "26fdaf5e-602e-4d6d-8480-80c576110494",
    "UntypedInstance": null,
    "InstanceType": null,
    "UseInstanceForProperties": false
}]
```

Comment: I would recommend sticking with NewtonSoft until this is resolved. I just ran into the same issue myself and I am using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData 7.4.1 Adding NewtonSoft to my project helped resolve the issue.